# Android Recycler View delete item

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-room, android-databinding, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

I have created a simple notes app that uses some of the Android Architecture components. I am using dataBinding to set data to my recycler view. One of the functionalities is bookmarking a note and displaying it in the Bookmarks fragment. In the Bookmarks fragment a user can tap the 'unbookmark' icon to remove a bookmarked note. I have used a simple on click listener on the icon inside my Bookmarks Recycler View Adapter to achieve this. I have a boolean property in my notes entity. Inside the Bookmarks fragment I update the bookmarks boolean value to false when the user taps the icon so that it changes to a false value(meaning it's not bookmarked and does not appear in the bookmarks fragment). However, when I click the 'unbookmark' icon the recycler view still displays the notes removed from the bookmarks.

Here is my Bookmarks Adapter :

```
class BookmarksAdapter(private var bookmarksList: List<Note>, var context: Context):
        RecyclerView.Adapter<BookmarksAdapter.BookmarkViewHolder>(), CoroutineScope {

    private lateinit var job: Job
    var deletedId : Int? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BookmarkViewHolder {

        val layoutItemBinding: BookmarksLayoutItemBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                R.layout.bookmarks_layout_item,
                parent,
                false)
        job = Job()

        return BookmarkViewHolder(layoutItemBinding.root)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BookmarkViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val bookmarkNote: Note = bookmarksList.get(position)

        holder.bookmarkBinding?.setVariable(BR.bookmarkItem, bookmarkNote)

        holder.bookmarkBinding?.executePendingBindings()

        holder.bookmarkBinding?.imageRemoveBookmark?.setOnClickListener {
            removeBookmark(bookmarkNote, position)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return bookmarksList.size
    }

    inner class BookmarkViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        var bookmarkBinding: BookmarksLayoutItemBinding? = DataBindingUtil.bind(itemView)
    }

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + Dispatchers.Main

    fun deleteNote(note : Note) {

        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            note.isBookmarked = false
            NotesDatabase(context).getDao().updateNote(note)
        }

        val pos = bookmarksList.toMutableList().indexOf(note)
        bookmarksList.toMutableList().removeAt(pos)
        notifyItemRemoved(pos)
    }

    // Remove a bookmark
    fun removeBookmark(bookmarkNote: Note, removedPos: Int) {

        bookmarkNote.isBookmarked = false

        launch (Dispatchers.IO){
            NotesDatabase(context).getDao().updateNote(bookmarkNote)

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                bookmarksList.toMutableList().removeAt(removedPos)
                notifyItemRemoved(removedPos)
                notifyItemRangeChanged(removedPos, 1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my Bookmarks View Model:

```
 class BookmarksViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val myContext: Context = application.applicationContext

    private var _bookmarksList = MutableLiveData<List<Note>>()

    val bookmarksList : LiveData<List<Note>>
        get() = _bookmarksList

    init{
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _bookmarksList.value = getNotes()
        }
    }

    suspend fun getNotes() : List<Note> = NotesDatabase(myContext).getDao().getBookmarkedNotes()

}
```

Here is my Bookmarks Fragment:

```
class BookmarksFragment : BaseFragment(){

    private lateinit var bookmarksBinding: FragmentBookmarksBinding
    private lateinit var bookmarksViewModel: BookmarksViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        bookmarksBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_bookmarks, container, false)
        bookmarksViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(BookmarksViewModel::class.java)

        // Observe the list of bookmarks
        bookmarksViewModel.bookmarksList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { bList ->
            bookmarksBinding.listOfBookmarks = bList
        })

        return bookmarksBinding.root

    }
}
```

Here is my Notes Entity:

```
val bookmarkSate: Boolean
    get() = true

@Entity
data class Note(

        val title : String,
        val note : String,
        var isBookmarked : Boolean = false
) : Serializable{
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var noteID : Int = 0
}
```

Here is my Notes DAO:

```
@Dao
interface NoteDao {

    @Insert
    suspend fun saveNote(note : Note)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM note ORDER BY noteID DESC")
    suspend fun getAllNotes() : List<Note>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM note WHERE isBookmarked")
    suspend fun getBookmarkedNotes() : List<Note>

    // add multiple notes
    @Insert
    suspend fun addMultipleNotes(vararg note: Note)

    @Update
    suspend fun updateNote(note: Note)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteNote(note : Note)
}
```

I am stuck on how to achieve the desired functionality of 'unbookmarking' a note and making it 'disappear 'from the bookmarks fragment. Kindly anyone who can help out?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems and possible solutions I see here:

1-) In your adapter, in your delete method, you have this piece of code:

```
val pos = bookmarksList.toMutableList().indexOf(note)
        bookmarksList.toMutableList().removeAt(pos)
        notifyItemRemoved(pos)
```

The problem here is that `toMutableList()` doesn't change your bookmarksList as mutable, it returns a **new** mutable list filled with the items in your bookmarkList, a mutable version of your list, but a new list! So you remove the item from this new list, and not from the original list. Simply correcting this could fix the problem. (You can define the bookmarksList as a mutable list from the beginning)

2-) You seem to observe the list from your viewmodel, it is livedata in your viewmodel. But it is not defined as livedata in your dao. So you are not observing the changes in the database. So an alternative solution could be to observe the changes from the database by wrapping your list within a livedata in your dao.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM note WHERE isBookmarked")
    suspend fun getBookmarkedNotes() : LiveData<List<Note>>
```

But this second one would require some additional changes in your code.

Comment: I implemented the changes and everything works well. Thank you.

Comment: Great to hear it helped @Innocent_Kyalo If it worked for you, can you upvote and set the answer as selected answer, please? That gives reputation points to the person who helped and that's the manner of saying thank you in Stackoverflow world :)